# Leave space around google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to add 10px space around the google map. I'm using google api and showing the polygon in the map. Please see the image for better understanding of what I'm looking for.

[image: Leave 10px space around google map]

Comment: Space around the map or a rectangle inside the map?

Comment: @scaisEdge Rectangular mark I drew should contain the whole map, you see the polygon is cut off through the rectangle but it should be accomadated within the rectangle. and leave the 10px space or padding outside the rectangle that can be filled with blue color or something. Another thing the top left map, satellite button and bottom right zoom button should be at the edge of the rectangle. I mean it wouldn't be something like that whole map will be reduced to the rectangle and still there's a gap between the edge of the rectangle and those buttons. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple space you can try adding a css margin to the div map

suppose that you div map is #map

```
#map {
  /* margin 10px; */
  border: 10px solid #ff0;
}
```

or directly in your html div

```
<div id='map' style="margin: 10px;'>
```

for the rectangle inside the map you must convert (when zoom change) the distance in px and then draw the rectangle

this sample form google developer could be useful https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates?csw=1